# Using Grunt Start Webdriver in project

Tags: gruntjs

I'm trying to use the [Grunt Start Webdriver](https://github.com/mbriggs/grunt-start-webdriver) plugin in my app. At this time, I can't get it to work. I have my Grunt task setup like the following:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'clean:temp',
    'compile:all',
    'copy:tests',
    'webdriver:test',
    'protractor:test'
  ]);
};
```

Everything works, except for the addition of webdriver:test. That task is defined in a file called webdriver.js. Its setup like this:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  return {
    webdriver: {
      options: {
        // Task-specific options go here.
      },
      test: {
        // Target-specific file lists and/or options go here.
      },
    },    
  };
};
```

When the webdriver:test task is reached, I get an error that says:

```
Verifying property webdriver.test exists in config...ERROR
>> Unable to process task.
Warning: Required config property "webdriver.test" missing. Use --force to continue.
```

I can't figure out where its looking for the property at. Or, why its not working. Can anybody provide some insights. My grunt file and tasks are structured like that of Kibana in case you're curious.

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "Verifying property \_\_\_ exists in config" mean in Grunt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26469127/what-does-verifying-property-exists-in-config-mean-in-grunt)